# Дата изменения файла в миллисекундах и сортировка

Tags: java, дата, время

Нужно, чтобы код по первым буквам возвращал список классов по дате последнего изменения( сначала новые). Если одинаковая дата изменения (допустим сохранили всё разом), то по алфавиту(от А до Z). 
Сделано уже очень многое, остались правки.

Проблемы следующие - почему то оно считает дату модификации всех файлов Thu Jan 01 05:00:00 PKT 1970
При нажатии на "сохранить всё", значение не меняется. Второе. Оно выводит  дату  и время в таком формате(смотри выше), а надо бы в миллисекундах. По мануалу

```
 Date tm = new Date(file.lastModified());
```

вроде и должно выводить милисекунды, а оно выводит зачем то 
Thu Jan 01 05:00:00 PKT 1970.

Вот полный код с комментариями.

```
 package com.company;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;


 public class Main {

static final String CLASS_FILE_EXTENSION = ".class";

/**
 * сортировка по дате последних изменений
 */
static final Comparator<File> MODIFIED_DATE_FILE_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
     public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
        if (o1.lastModified() > o2.lastModified()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            if (o1.lastModified() == o2.lastModified()) {
                System.out.println("проверочка");// текст выводиться отсюда аж 19 раз, значит даты модификации все одинаковые
                //либо что то не так написано
                return o1.getAbsolutePath().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getAbsolutePath());

            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeMap<File, Class> classesByFiles = find("com.company", ""); // получил мапу
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<>(classesByFiles.keySet()); //получил список файлов из мапы
    Collections.sort(files, MODIFIED_DATE_FILE_COMPARATOR);// посортировал

    // теперь можно бежать по отсортированному циклу и брать классы сначала от старых файлов двигаясь к более молодым
    for (File file : files) {
        Class cls = classesByFiles.get(file);
        System.out.println(file);
        Date tm = new Date(file.lastModified());
        System.out.println(tm);
        //оно выводит Thu Jan 01 05:00:00 PKT 1970, непонятно почему.
        //вперемешку выводится название всех классов по алфавиту. Но они и в IDE отсортированы по алфавиту.
        // Или это происходит из-за TreeMap?
    }
}


/**
 * метод соберет и разложит по мапе классы из заданного package
 */
public static TreeMap<File, Class> find(String pkgname, String beginStr) {



    String relPath = pkgname.replace('.', '/');

    URL resource = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(relPath);
    assert resource != null;
    File directory = new File(resource.getPath());

    if (directory != null && directory.exists()) {
        // Получаем список всех файлов в папке
        String[] files = directory.list();
        TreeMap<File, Class> resMap = new TreeMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            // Берем только файлы с расширением .class
            if (!files[i].endsWith(CLASS_FILE_EXTENSION)) {
                continue;
            }
            File file = new File(files[i]);


            String className = files[i].substring(0, files[i].lastIndexOf('.'));

            try {
                resMap.put(file, Class.forName(pkgname + "." + className));
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //тут надо бы сделать чтобы с первых букв оно выводило классы которые начинаються на эти буквы.
            // Но это не главное. Главное чтобы время нормальное было. А то беда какая то
            if (className.toLowerCase().substring(0, beginStr.length()).equals(beginStr.toLowerCase())) {
                String fullClassName = pkgname + '.' + className;
            }

        }
        return resMap;
    }
    return null;

}
```

}

Comment: файловая система скорее всего отдает вам количество секунд, а не миллисекунд.

Comment: Благодарю, а можно подробнее? Как то не слишком информативно. Как это исправить? Гугл по запросу "файловая система отдает секунды вместо миллисекунд" выдает не то что нужно

Comment: нет, я понятия не имею, что там внутри. но это только джава зачем-то ведет весь отсчет в миллисекундах, весь мир считает количество секунд от unix epoch time. понятно, что для большинства операций секунда - слишком большое округление, но основа всех основ - это timestamp в виде количества секунд.

Comment: Возможно он просто не находит файл! Но как он его не находит если ему дано даже его название, и список названий то успешно выходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

по поводу даты изменения файлов. Тут ошибка при создании объекта файл. Когда он создается, ему подается неправильный путь:

```
File file = new File(files[i]);//в результате получаем файл втекущей директории, то есть в директории проекта
```

надо:

```
File file = new File(directory + "\\" + files[i]); // вот теперь путь верный.
```

дополнительно стоит проверить, существует ли файл вот [этим](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()) методом. 
А если все правильно и файлы существуют, то метод lastModified() вернет корректное значение

2. по поводу формата вывода даты.

надо просто вызывать метод getTime() у даты для вывода количества миллисекунд

```
System.out.println(tm.getTime());
```

Answer (score 2):

[`File.lastModified()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29) возвращает `0L`, если файла нет, или произошла какая-то ошибка. В данном случае, у вас `directory.list()` вернула массив *имен* файлов в папке `directory`, а объект `File` разрешает неабсолютные пути (не начинающиеся с корневого каталога) относительно рабочей папки программы. В рабочей папке файлов с такими именами нет, поэтому всегда возвращается 0.

Для решения проблемы можно использовать [`File.listFiles()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) который возвращает сразу `File[]`, либо создавать объекты конструктором [`new File(directory, files[i])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29).

Еще можно переехать на новое (Java SE 7 вышла всего-то в 2011ом) api, в нем предназначенный для получения времени изменения метод [`Files.getLastModifiedTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getLastModifiedTime%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) при отсутствии файла кидает исключение.

Comment: Мне бы чуть подробнее. Вместо чего использовать File.listFiles()? как при этом осуществить сортировку? (изначальная задача - сортировка по дате, а если дата одинаковая - то по алфавиту)